# Vim autoindent (gg=G) is terribly broken for JS indentation

Tags: javascript, vim, indentation, eslint

My end goal here is to use `gg=G` to autoindent all of my JS code compliant to an `eslintrc.js` file.

So, currently I have [`syntastic`](https://github.com/vim-syntastic/syntastic/tree/master/syntax_checkers/javascript) and [`vim-javascript`](https://github.com/pangloss/vim-javascript) looking at my JS code with the following in my `.vimrc`

```
let g:syntastic_javascript_checkers=["eslint"]
```

Lets say that I have some decent JS like the following

```js
const path = require('path');

const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

const PATHS = {
  app : path.join(__dirname, 'app'),
  build : path.join(__dirname, 'build'),
};

const commonConfig = {
  entry : {
    app : PATHS.app,
  },
  output : {
    path : PATHS.build,
    filename : '[name].js',
  },
  plugins : [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title : 'Webpack Demo',
    }),
  ],
};
```

The `gg=G` (normal mode) command mutilates the above into the following.

```js
const path = require('path');

const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

const PATHS = {
app : path.join(__dirname, 'app'),
      build : path.join(__dirname, 'build'),
};

const commonConfig = {
entry : {
app : PATHS.app,
        },
output : {
path : PATHS.build,
       filename : '[name].js',
         },
plugins : [
              new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
title : 'Webpack Demo',
}),
],
    };
```

Which is not cool.

Btw, [`vim-js-indent`](https://github.com/gavocanov/vim-js-indent) and [`vim-jsx-improve`](https://github.com/neoclide/vim-jsx-improve) didn't do anything either.

Any help is very welcome, many thanks are in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your "not cool" example is the result of the "generic" indenting you get when Vim didn't recognize your buffer as JavaScript and/or didn't apply JavaScript-specific indentation rules.

That code is indented correctly with this minimal setup:

```
$ vim -Nu NONE --cmd 'filetype indent on' filename.js
```

which:

- detects that your buffer contains JavaScript,
- applies JavaScript-specific indentation rules.

To ensure proper indenting, you must add this line to your `vimrc`:

```
filetype indent on
```

Comment: I'm ashamed it's so simple! Odd part is that indentation was fine with other filetypes. Oh well, my world is a better place now.